# Wordpress Plugin Activate / Deactive Failing

Tags: plugin-development, activation, deactivation

Below is my plugin.php file that would install into `wp-content`

```
 <?php    // If this file is called directly, abort.
    namespace Booker;
    if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
        die;
    }

 /**
 * Currently plugin version.
 * Start at version 1.0.0 and use SemVer - https://semver.org
 * Rename this for your plugin and update it as you release new versions.
 */
define( 'PLUGIN_NAME_VERSION', '1.0.0' );

/**
 * The code that runs during plugin activation.
 * This action is documented in includes/class-booker-activator.php
 */
function activate_booker() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/class-booker-activator.php';
    error_log("Running Activation");
    Booker_Activator::activate();
}

/**
 * The code that runs during plugin deactivation.
 * This action is documented in includes/class-booker-deactivator.php
 */
function deactivate_booker() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/class-booker-deactivator.php';
    error_log("Running Deactivation");
    Booker_Deactivator::deactivate();
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_booker');
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate_booker');

?>
```

It certainly is not executing but the plugin deactivates and activates as expected. Currently, there is no code in the function calls defined inside those functions....but the lack of the log message shows no execution.
However, I am getting the problem:

> The plugin generated 2368 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems
>   with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
>   this plugin.

And in my logs I get:

```
[08-Oct-2019 23:51:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'activate_booker' not found or invalid function name in G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 286
[08-Oct-2019 23:51:20 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[08-Oct-2019 23:51:20 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-admin\plugins.php:0
[08-Oct-2019 23:51:20 UTC] PHP   2. activate_plugin() G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-admin\plugins.php:44
[08-Oct-2019 23:51:20 UTC] PHP   3. do_action() G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-admin\includes\plugin.php:672
[08-Oct-2019 23:51:20 UTC] PHP   4. WP_Hook->do_action() G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php:465
[08-Oct-2019 23:51:20 UTC] PHP   5. WP_Hook->apply_filters() G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php:310
```

And also

```
[09-Oct-2019 00:44:43 UTC] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'deactivate_booker' not found or invalid function name in G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 286
[09-Oct-2019 00:44:43 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Oct-2019 00:44:43 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-admin\plugins.php:0
[09-Oct-2019 00:44:43 UTC] PHP   2. deactivate_plugins($plugins = *uninitialized*, $silent = *uninitialized*, $network_wide = *uninitialized*) G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-admin\plugins.php:192
[09-Oct-2019 00:44:43 UTC] PHP   3. do_action($tag = *uninitialized*, $arg = *uninitialized*) G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-admin\includes\plugin.php:792
[09-Oct-2019 00:44:43 UTC] PHP   4. WP_Hook->do_action($args = *uninitialized*) G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php:465
[09-Oct-2019 00:44:43 UTC] PHP   5. WP_Hook->apply_filters($value = *uninitialized*, $args = *uninitialized*) G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php:310
```

Additional error when I changed the function names:

```
[09-Oct-2019 02:08:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'booker_deactivate' not found or invalid function name in G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 286
[09-Oct-2019 02:08:03 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Oct-2019 02:08:03 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-admin\plugins.php:0
[09-Oct-2019 02:08:03 UTC] PHP   2. deactivate_plugins() G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-admin\plugins.php:192
[09-Oct-2019 02:08:03 UTC] PHP   3. do_action() G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-admin\includes\plugin.php:792
[09-Oct-2019 02:08:03 UTC] PHP   4. WP_Hook->do_action() G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php:465
[09-Oct-2019 02:08:03 UTC] PHP   5. WP_Hook->apply_filters() G:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php:310
```

Comment: As an aside the server is in development mode so I suspect the headers sent message is to do with the PHP notices getting sent re the warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the 'activate_plugin' was a typo in the question. But even so, as a friendly reminder (for all of us), [`activate_plugin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/activate_plugin/) is an existing function in WordPress. And you should use unique prefix in your custom functions (that are defined in the *global* scope):

```php
function my_plugin_activate_plugin() {
  ...
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate_plugin' );
```

### The Problem and Its Solution

The error/warning in the logs which says `function 'activate_booker' not found or invalid function name` happens because you're using a namespace in your file and you failed to properly reference to the callback function in your namespace:

```php
// Incorrect - These are referencing to global functions.
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_booker' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate_booker' );

// Correct syntax when referencing to namespace functions.
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'Booker\activate_booker' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'Booker\deactivate_booker' );

// Or use the __NAMESPACE__ constant.
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, __NAMESPACE__ . '\activate_booker' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, __NAMESPACE__ . '\deactivate_booker' );
```

Note though, unless a fatal error was encountered, the plugin would still be activated/deactivated; it's just that the activation/deactivation callback wouldn't be called.

And here's a good [article](https://stevegrunwell.com/blog/php-namespaces-wordpress/) which talks about using PHP namespaces in WordPress.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific my plugin is called booker...anywhere you see the word plugin it would be booker in the code so the function is `activate_booker()` in the file booker.php

Comment: I generified the code before posting

Comment: Try `function activate_booker() { error_log( 'Plugin activated' ); }` and `function deactivate_booker() { error_log( 'Plugin deactivated' ); }` (I suppose the deactivation function is `deactivate_booker` ?)

Comment: so I did something similar as I had already tried activate_booker() instead I used booker_activate() because I head read that there is a hook / filter list called `activate_YOUR_PLUGIN_NAME` that is created and while my function name shouldnt conflict I wanted it clear.

Comment: So I amended my question with the new error message..@Sally-CJ

Comment: Based on the logs, I'm guessing you probably left a code in your file which hooks to the plugin activation/deactivation and calls a function named 'activate/deactivate_plugin' that doesn't exist. Try looking for that hook/code or comment out all code which is relevant to the issue. That might help you find the source of the problem.

Comment: Oh one thing I forgot and I am not sure if it matter the file is NAMESPACED
`namespace Booker;`

Comment: Also when I changed the function call name it definitely changed the hooks function name to be correct - but its not calling the hook on the correct file - OR those functions (and thier names) for some reason are not cached

Comment: So thats confirmed when called a namespaced file even tho its not Classed you would use `register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'NameSpace/my_plugin_activate_plugin' );

Comment: Sally if you update your answer I can accept it thanks for the help

Comment: Great answer covers all the bases